# TypeError: props is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react video player app that makes api calls to youtube and presents a user with a list of 5 videos and lets them play the first Video returned in the VideoDetail component. However, I'm being haunted by the above error and yet i feel like i appropriately added the constructors to my class-based components. Any help on how to go about this error will be highly appreciated. 
Here is code for my index.js file.

This file contains the app(parent) component.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail from './components/video_detail';

const API_KEY = 'MyApiKey';

class App extends Component(){
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {videos: []};

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'internet of things'}, (videos) => {
      this.SetState({videos});
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
          <div>
          <SearchBar />
          <VideoDetail video={this.state.videos[0]} />
          <VideoList videos = {this.state.videos} />
          </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

video_detail.js file has code for the VideoDetail component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = ({video}) =>{
  if (!video){
    return(
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  }

  const videoId = video.id.videoId;
  const url = `www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

  return(
    <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
      <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src = {url}></iframe>
      </div>
      <div className="details">
      <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
      <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default VideoDetail;
```

video_list_item.js contains code for the VideoListItem component

```js
import React from 'react';

const VideoListItem = ({video}) =>{

const imgUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

  return(
    <li className = "list-group-item">
    <div className ="video-list media" >
        <div className ="media-left">
          <img className = "media-object" src = {imgUrl}/>
        </div>

        <div className = "media-body">
          <div className = "media-heading">{video.snippet.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
}

export default VideoListItem;
```

video_list.js contains code for the VideoList component as shown below

```js
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

const VideoList = (props) => {
  const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem video = {video} key = {video.etag} />;
  });
  return(
    <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
      {videoItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default VideoList;
```

search_bar.js contains code for the SearchBar component i have not yet wired though.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {term: ''};
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <input />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: I think you need to make `VideoList ` as react component before accessing props in it.

Answer (score 1):

In your App file change `class App extends Component() {`
 to `class App extends Component {` and `this.SetState` in line 17 to `this.setState`